# Change the value of key of a foreach loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the value of key of a foreach loop in javascript.

```
response.forEach(function (item, index) { 
<a data-id="+index+"></a>    
});
```

Suppose if the page is 1 then index should start from 0 and if the page is 2 it should start from 31 and if the page is 3 the index should start from 61.

Is is possible?

**Example**

In my html I am increasing the value of `data-id` on foreach loop. And also I am appending data on page scroll. So everytime I scroll the page the index starts from 0. That is why I want to skip the numbers of previous scroll.

Result with my code:

```
<a data-id="0"></a>
<a data-id="1"></a>
<a data-id="2"></a>
<a data-id="3"></a>
<a data-id="4"></a>
....
<a data-id="30"></a>
<a data-id="0"></a>
```

So you see the index starts from 0 again so I want to skip 30 and continue the numbering from 31

Comment: can you give us an example.

Comment: @Sascha I have added some explaination. Can you please go through it?

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to keep track of the last index you setup and just increment it.

I.E. something like this.

```
// this should be placed in a way that is 'global' to your module, so it remains evaluated. 
//It starts from -1 because so at first element added it becames 0
var maxIdx=-1; 

response.forEach(function (item, index) {
maxIdx++;
<a data-id="+maxIdx+"></a>    
});
```

Hope it is what you expect